# I am getting a URI Redirect error for an Azure Application even though the URIs match

Tags: azure, authentication, oauth-2.0

I am building my first Azure application and am getting this error when I try to authenticate

AADSTS50011: The redirect URI 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/getAToken' specified in the request does not match the redirect URIs configured for the application

When I go into Azure and look at the redirect URI this is what the value is set to:
http://localhost:5000/getAToken

The app is running locally on http://127.0.0.1:5000

What am I missing here? The URIs match exactly right? So why am I getting this error?

Comment: Try by using `127.0.0.1` or `localhost` in both places. Either change the redirect URI in app settings to `http://127.0.0.1:5000/getAtToken` or run your application using `http://localhost:5000`.

Comment: Are you getting "More details: Reply address did not match because requested address had a trailing slash." in the end of the error message?

Answer (score 0):

The redirect URI is matched as a string, not as a DNS-resolved URL. That means that `localhost` does not equal `127.0.0.1` in this case.

As Gaurav said you would have to use the same value in both places — either `localhost` or `127.0.0.0`, but it has to be the same string value.

It doesn't matter how you access your app, you can still access it through `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`. The thing that matters is the value that you send in the redirect_uri parameter. So, if in Azure you have the value `http://localhost:5000/getAToken` then send `http://localhost:5000/getAToken` in the `redirect_uri` parameter.